# Shamir secret sharing in automated verification tools

Tags: provable-security, secret-sharing, security-definition, semantic-security, verifiability

Can Shamir secret sharing scheme (SSS) be verified using automated verification tools such as AVISPA? I read in the HLPSL manual that we cannot use arithmetic or relative operations such +,-,< ...etc in the HLPSL description of the protocol. Thus, we cannot implement LaGrange's interpolation formula?!! Do all protocol verification have this limitation?

(There are other protocol verification tools, but recently, I got familiar with AVISPA)

Comment: Did you take a look at Verifpal?

Comment: Arxiv 1805.12482 "..Towards Formal Proof for Secure Multi-Party Computation"

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Thank you for sharing this paper, I am reading it now.

Comment: @AaqibBashir Is Verifpal any different from AVISPA?

Comment: Verifpal is one of the state-of-the-art tools for verification of cryptographic protocols. For more understanding you can read https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/971.pdf